# jsf 1.2 Custom tag, read parameter in backing bean

Tags: jsf

I don't understand how to pass parameters from my custom tag to the backing bean and read it.

I want to set an attribute in my custom tag and have this value read in the backing bean, like this:

taglib: **lstOperatorDomain.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<body>

    <ui:composition>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{textParameter}"/>       
        <h:commandButton value="Prueba" action="#{lstOperatorDomainController.prueba}"/>
    </h:form> 
    </ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

client of the taglib: **console.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:cs="http://www.sdd.com.ar/cuentasimple/facelets">
<body>

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">Console</ui:define>     
        <ui:define name="body">

            <cs:lstOperatorDomain textParameter="Testing123" />

            ...other things...

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

The important part is, **how can I read the value from textParameter ("Testing123") in my back bean lstOperatorDomainController ?**

I've tried many things and in most of them I got an 'Illegal Syntax for Set Operation'

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter as a named component parameter:

```
<h:commandButton value="Prueba" action="#{lstOperatorDomainController.prueba}">
  <f:param name="my_param" value="#{textParameter}" />
</h:commandButton>
```